# Some (not all) hyphenated words contain "return" character

Tags: symbols, miktex, hyphenation

In a document being built with MikTeX, some auto hyphenation is being done with a "return" character (a left pointing arrow with a riser at the right end) instead of a hyphen. This seems to happen mostly in all-caps words, but it sometimes happens in initial-caps and lower case words. What could cause it?

I'm far from a TeX expert, but I learned that the hyphenation character can be changed by the `\hyphenchar` command. I assume that it can be changed for specific styles, which could account for the inconsistent appearance. However, I searched all of the source files I could find and I didn't find any instances of `\hyphenchar`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without an example of code showing the issue it's really difficult to make a guess.

Comment: it could be hyphenchar set to a different value (try `\showthe\hyphenchar\font` to see) It could (potentially) be that the font you are using has a return character in position 45, or it could be something else. With no example, impossible to guess.